# How to tell what rotation operation a matrix performs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rotations

For example, a matrix $ M= \begin{bmatrix} cos^2(a) & -sin(a) & -cos(a)sin(a)\\ cos(a)sin(a) & cos(a) & -sin^2(a) \\ sin(a) & 0 & cos(a) \end{bmatrix}$. What is the axis and angle of this rotation?

Answer (score 1):

The axis will be in the direction of the eigenvector of $M$ for the eigenvalue $1$.

The angle is recoverable from the equation $Tr(M)=1+2\cos(\theta)$. When solving for $\theta$, you'll have to be careful to get the sign of rotation to match the eigenvector you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions).
Section "Formalism Alternatives" subsection "Rotation Matrix" shows how to get the rotation angle and axis from the matrix.

Comment: Instead of just linking to the answer, you should try to explain the method here and link to Wikipedia for more info.

Comment: The Wikipedia link is a good entry.  I would just be repeating what they say.

Comment: Then this should be a comment rather than an answer.  Answers with just links are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Your axis is given by the eigen vector $v$ such as $Mv=v$ (eigen value : $1$)

Let $u$ be a vector perpendicular to $v$ then $cos(\theta)=\frac{(Mu,u)}{||u||^2}$